Git & GitLab: Keeping a master config file, branch changes discarded upon merging with master
I'm working on building out a GitLab workflow for a team transitioning from Perforce.
I'm testing out making a 'testsuites.txt' file that has a list of testsuites; upon commit, a CI job runs a script that generates a downstream pipeline .yml with separate jobs for each unit test suite listed, which the results of are uploaded as artifacts to the downstream pipeline. For reference, we're using CMake & CTest, so each of these separate unit test job runs a single ctest -R "${testname}" command. The advantage of this is that devs can easily configure which unit tests they want to run for a feature they're working on in a branch. This codebase has a lot of small changes committed often and running every unit test in every branch is without a doubt a waste of time and resources.
But upon merge to master, we want to ensure every test in the suite (or a subset of the tests that is necessary for production) is run. Is there a way to do this easily with Git/GitLab, either through CI pipelines or some branch infrastructure? Or do we just have to have this managed by the merge reviewer?
I've already tried using .gitattributes set up like this:
# prioritizes the master branch's testsuites.txt if there is a conflict
testsuites.txt merge=ours

but it seems this will only work if there's actually a merge conflict; I don't think I want to induce an artificial merge conflict just so this would work.
I also realized that we still want devs to be able to add new tests upon adding new features... so we don't just want to outright drop the branch's version of testsuites.txt.
The thought that I had was checking in the runner if we were in the master branch, and if we were, ignore the list in testsuites.txt and instead using a mastertestsuites.txt or something similar, and renaming testsuites.txt -> branchtestsuites.txt, but I have not tried implementing this yet.
